# Java Socket Accept Connection from one IP

Tags: sockets, java

How to create a server socket which accept connection from a specific ip address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new ServerSocket(1234, 50, InetAddress.getByName("1.2.3.4"));`

Where
1234 - port
1.2.3.4 - the IP to listen to. So, if you have 2 IP addresses on 1 machine (1.2.3.4 and 1.2.3.5) the code above will subscribe to the first IP only.

Comment: Aha, and what is the backlog for? (50)

Comment: Hey, it's not really "from a specific IP address" - it will accept connections from any host. What this call does, is creates a socket that listens on the specific IP on the server machine. You need a `SecurityManager` installed, or a custom `ServerSocket` implementation to accept connections only from specific addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.nio/NbServerSocket.html